# Do I need Kibana/ Grafana or I can do the same with Google Cloud Operations OOTB suite?

Tags: monitoring, stackdriver

I have a customer that have Kibana for application logging monitoring and now is moving to GCP, but the question is Do they still need Kibana for application logging monitoring, Dashboards ? or they can have the same features using Google Cloud Operations suite.

Thanks for your inputs

Comment: Did you had time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem? If yes, Please consider to accept and upvote it. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but using kibana/ grafana along with Google Cloud Operations suite depends on your requirement.

For example, Google Cloud's operations suite is not ready for Oracle DB. There is a feature request to collect the Oracle metrics, but it might be available in next quarter. In the meanwhile, you have an alternative option for Google GCP customers to collect Oracle metrics by utilizing Prometheus and Grafana.
Use Google Cloud's operations suite to monitor resources as well as Grafana and Prometheus for container monitoring.

Kibana lets users visualize data with charts and graphs in Elasticsearch. On the other hand, Google Cloud's operations suite is detailed as "Monitoring, logging, and diagnostics for applications on Google Cloud Platform and AWS".

You can use a kibana alongside a Google Cloud's operations suite for further analysis of logs and to gain insight.